# Is there a tool to help identify linker errors?

Tags: c++

C++ link errors are most of the times the hardest to nail down. Even in [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012), the linker messages are long, cryptic and with mangled symbols, but the worst part is: there is no helper tool to show you where the error occurs, and you can spend very long frustrating minutes trying to figure out the problem. Is there any add-in tool out there to help nail down linker errors?

What I'd expect from the tool is to open the relevant source files at the line in error, display a graph of binaries and dependencies in which the remedy could be found, etc.

For example, in the case of multiply defined symbols, have the tool open all the locations in which the symbol is defined in their project contexts, and suggest a solution.

Comment: The error is *always* in your link line, unless it is not, then it is probably in a header file and such a tool may be useful. `clang` is famous for the least cryptic error messages.

Comment: As a tip, multiple definition errors is most likely that you have _defined_ a symbol in a header file instead of just _declaring_ it. Like defining a function or class method, but forgetting to make it `inline`.

Comment: There are other reasons, such as including the same cpp file in several projects then trying to link one with another.

Comment: Even Visual Studio with its mangled names is mostly very clear about in which TU's the multiple definitions are found or the missing definitions referenced. They are not too hard to read.

Comment: Well try this:   DebugMyLibStub.lib(MyLib.dll) : error LNK2005: "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::get_system_category(void)" (?get_system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) already defined in my_common_lib.lib(error_code.obj)

In what file in MyLib.dll is the symbol in question defined?

Comment: Well, obviously it's about the function `get_system_category` from Boost.System. It's either a non-inline function defined in a header you included twice, or you linked the same object or lib file into both libs. Since Boost has well tested libraries and Boost.System is *not* header-only, one can assume that you linked the Boost.System lib file into `MyLib.dll` as well as into `my_common_lib.lib`. The name of the latter sounds like that kind of "just grab everythign I'll ever need" library that is predestined for such kind of errors.

Comment: Arne, everything you say is right. The problem is to find *where* the symbols are defined. I'm looking for a tool that would open the files etc. etc. like I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: To find symbol dependencies and their resolution, I've always referenced the map file. You might have to poke around with options to generate it depending on the toolchain. VStudio might put that info in the PDB too but it's been years since I've touched VS. Usually it's faster for me to go the earliest link error, resolve it, recompile - rinse lather repeat.

Comment: I guess the short answer is "no". One approach may be to write a such a tool. A better one would be to take an open-source linker and improve the error reporting.